TMC5160 stepper drivers don't enable the motor, "supply short to Phase B" bits set, driver error
I tried to create a board based on BigTreeTech TMC5160 Stepper driver with encoder functions and pure SPI driver instead of using DIR/STEP.
However, I triple checked the layout and still it didn't work as expected. Using the same schematic I made two different layout. One has issue with SPI communications, it's all garbage data but able to power it on sometimes. The second cannot even power up, but SPI works good this time.
I was hoping some experts can help me with layout and gave me some hope and directions.
I attach my schematic and layout, I also put on github for anyone who can help me check the layout.
I'm pretty sure it's this board layout issue since I tested BigTreeTech board and SilentStep boards and they all work fine with the same setup.
https://github.com/xukangmin/TMC5160_stepper_driver


